# how to get iOS app notified whenever user switches between wifi networks

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability, system-configuration

As far as my understanding, with the help of Reachability code, you can make your app get notified whenever there is a change in network type(say 3G or Wifi), but it does not seem to be possible to get notified upon switching between different wifi networks(from one ssid to different ssid). Is there anyway to get your iOS app notified whenever user switches between wifi networks. If yes, is it possible to do the same when the app is in background.

Comment: I am pretty sure Reachability will ping your app on network change and then you can use a combined solution where you copy SSID of network and compare against previous one. This should be much more efficient than NSTimer.

Comment: @Andy - Thanks for the reply. I will check if Reachability notifies upon one ssid to another ssid switching.

Comment: @thelaws, Monolo, fredtantini, Josh Burgess, gtgaxiola - How to detect wifi switching when the app is in background does not seem to be answered in the mentioned question. :-)